# Instance not picking up

Tags: c#

I tried to make it so that the "word" variable is consistent everywhere in my program, as well as able to be used in private functions, what I was trying to do with the set is to set the words value to the return that a random word generator gives me. If I instantiate the class in which the GetWord() method is, in several places, it gives me different words, any tips?

```
 public static char[] Word
        {
            get { return word; } 
            set {
                Words w = new Words();
                word = w.GetWord();
                word = value;
                }
```

// was hoping to be able to use the "word" variable where I want and have it remain consistent.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The first 2 lines in your setter are useless, because the last one will set `word=value`. `x=4;x=2` – the first assignment can be removed without any ill effect.

Answer (score 2):

When you mark a property as `static`, it doesn't evaluate the statements in its setter and getter. You should probably use `static class` with a static constructor. [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).

For example:

```
public static class MyWord
{
    private static readonly char[] m_word;
    
    static MyWord()
    {
        var words = new Words();
        m_word = words.GetWord();
    }

    public static char[] Word => m_word;
}
```

Comment: I ended up rewriting my code in a way which all variables are under one class, I'm a first year uni student and this is my first real coding project so I was trying to impress my lecturer but to no avail. Thank you for the help tho, the resource you provided was very helpful and I think I understand constructors in general a bit better now.

Comment: @no-one, no worries. Experience builds up the more you read and code, challenges will push your limits and give you better understanding of how things work. Don't take shortcuts, learn the concepts, and teach yourself abstract thinking. Wish you best of luck!